# Growing mutt temporary file problem when sending attachments

Tags: mutt, files

I have an automysqlbackup.sh script that backs up and sends the database via cron. The script uses mutt to send the compressed file as attachment. I am on a shared hosting server.

It looks like mutt creates a temporary file named 'sent' in my home directory with all the headers and encoded attachment, and then fails to delete it. This file keeps growing with each attachment sent. I can't find any reference to this file in mutt's manual, according to the man page, mutt temporary files look like muttXXXXX.

Other than deleting the file manually, what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a temporary file, but your "sent-mail" folder, so this is expected behavior.

It should be possible to disable this with the command

```
set copy=no
```

in your `~/.muttrc` file